# Jquery unwrap p from div and wrap it in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to unwrap text from left and wrap into right, and then hide left. The only issue I have is that right is also wrapping around left, I think? When the `p` from left gets wrapped into right, right doubles its width.

How can I avoid this? Please have a look at my jsfiddle as it will probably explain things better than I can!

http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/9LGA9/1/

```
$('#button').click(function () {
       $(".left > p").unwrap().wrap('.right');
       $(".left").hide();
});
```

Comment: So is essentially what you're after to move the paragraph from the left div to the right div?

Comment: Yep, with a function, that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append()` or `appendTo()` should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhsLG/

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    $(".left > p").appendTo('.right');
    $(".left").hide();

});
```

When you use `append()` or `appendTo()` on an existing element, the element is simply moved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".left > p").appendTo('.right');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9LGA9/3/

Comment: I have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer but thank you! That is correct. : )

Comment: Actually, mine came 3 seconds later. :) @Jason P is the winner :). Plz accept his answer :)